# Angular 2 html injection output a string instead of html element

Tags: angular

i try to inject html content from a class but instead the result i get is a string instead of the html element, what am i doing wrong?

angular version : angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.20-4

html content:

```
<div [ngStyle]=getStyles()>{{getData()}}</div>
```

getData() return value:

```
"<span style='color:#5999B6'>this.data</span>"
```

this.data is a string

Comment: how does your `getData()` function looks like? what are you actually returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular don't allow direct injection of HTML in template for security reason. You need to sanitize your html. Follow following url to sanitize your HTML.
https://netbasal.com/angular-2-security-the-domsanitizer-service-2202c83bd90

Hope it will help

Comment: In fact, it does, I'm using it in production ^^. The issue is that the topic you linked asks to bypass the sanitization before injecting the string to template. If this string is linked to a user input, it'll lead to XSS injection for sure. The sanitizer is supposed to be here for that.

Answer (score 0):

You want to bind html using `innerHTML`:

```
<div [ngStyle]="getStyles()" [innerHTML]="getData()"></div>
```

But **BE CAREFUL**, you have to have full control over the html returned by `getData()` to avoid XSS issues.